# Edimax wireless router is not providing DNS services correctly

Tags: dns, wireless-router, dhcp-server

I have an Edimax router that is set up to connect to the internet via L2TP on cable, and on the LAN side it's set up as a DHCP server.

The DHCP server gives correct IP addresses, but it sets itself up as the DNS server.  However, it doesn't provide the DNS service.  I am sure that it's a problem with the router, because I have two computers on the network with the same problem.

I see that on the WAN side it gets correct DNS addresses from the ISP, so I'd expect the router to either pass these addresses through to the DHCP clients, or to serve the DNS requests itself by forwarding them to the ISP's DNS.  However, it apparently does neither, and there is no DNS.

I switched from ADSL to cable last week.  On ADSL it connected using PPPoE, and the DNS worked fine.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Quick hack: does your router allows you to set DNS manually? (It should, manufacturers are aware of Google's/OpenDNS server.. but no .local resolution then); did you updated firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me...

Rebooted the router... problem solved.